# How to get multiple contexts in langchain

Tags: langchain

I have a function where I call langchain as shown below. I pass in a {context} and a {question}.

Two questions:

1. How is the results of the vector store automatically assigned to {context}?
2. How can I pass in a second {context2}? Can I simply assign something to this variable, or is there a mechanism behind it?

   ```
   def answer_answer(collection_name, chroma_db_directory, llm, embedding, **kwargs):

    vectorstore = Chroma(
        collection_name=collection_name,
        persist_directory=chroma_db_directory, embedding_function=embedding
    )

    prompt_template = """
    This is a pair of template question and answer.
    {context}
    Continue the question by strongly considering the answer from the context.
    Answer that needs to be continued is below. If a sentence is started, make sure to just continue it: 
    {question}

    Continuation:"""

    PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
        template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question"]
    )

    log.info("Calling llm...")
    qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm=llm,
        chain_type="stuff",
        retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1}),
        chain_type_kwargs={"verbose": True, "prompt": PROMPT},
    )
    return qa
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Langchain can obfuscate a lot of things.

In fact chain_type stuff will combine all your documents into one document with a given separator.

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/libs/langchain/langchain/chains/combine_documents/stuff.py) and this is also explained in the docs [here](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains/document/stuff)

The default separator is \n\n (double line jump).